# How do I populate my model from a database entry?

Tags: asp.net, database, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have set up a large form with lots of entries.  It populates my model and then saves to the database.  I also need to be able to pull this information out of the database, put it into the model, and populate a bunch of fields with it for review.  How do I do this?

Using ASP.NET MVC 4 Razor.

```
var db = new TechProjPlansContext();

TechProjPlan model = new TechProjPlan();
```

I can set up my data context and model, but where do I go from here to populate the model with a data entry chosen by ID?

Answer (score 1):

You can search by givenId and if found return result type of TechProjPlan otherwise null

```
var resultFound = db.TechProjPlans.Where(e=>e.Id = givenId).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Ok that worked!  Now I have it in the object type TechProjPlan, which was the class generated from the database.  How can I get that into the model type TechProjPlanModel so I can pass it to the view, or do I even need to do that?

Comment: If you need extra fields then you can create new ViewModel, otherwise you can use existing model

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend following [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4) step by step. From the tutorial to answer your question:

Write a `Model` class like:

```
public class Movie 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Add a `DbSet` to your `Context` class: (`TechProjPlansContext` in your project)

```
public class MovieDBContext : DbContext 
{
    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; } 
}
```

Make sure you can connect to the database server, check your `connectionStrings` in your **Web.config** file.

As you wanted to filter only one **Entity** by using `ID`, you need a **Controller** class:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id = 0) // here id is set to 0 if it's null
{
    Movie movie = db.Movies.Find(id);
    if (movie == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(movie);
}
```

As you see, you'll be returning `View(movie)`, that means you return `Details page` with the `Entity` (a `movie`) you got from the database. And have a `View`, that renders to actual **HTML** code the client will see. At the top of it, add the line:

```
@model MvcMovie.Models.Movie  // (something TechProjPlans.Models.Movie in your project) 

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
```

This will create a simple text showing the movie's title.

It's not logical to go deeper within an answer, so rest is up to you with that tutorial. Just keep in mind that the code above is only one example and you can use endless variations within each level for your situation.

You can right click on the directory **Controllers**, select **Add New** and select your **Model** class and **Context** class at the page. That will produce a **Controller** and **Views** (index, edit, delete, details, insert) tied to it which will be a good way to start your **MVC** study.